# Given X sets of Y coin flips, what are the chances that at least one of the same index in each set shows heads?

Tags: probability

To clarify with an example:

If you were to flip two sets of 5 coins. What are the chances that both sets show heads at the same index at least once?

So if you were to flip this and the result was:

Set 1: H, T, H, H, H

Set 2: H, H, T, T, T

That means that the two sets match at index 0 (the first result).

So my question is, what are the chances that this happens? As more flips are added, the probability climbs ever close to 100%; but as more sets are added, the probability decreases. What would be the formula that I could use if I wanted, at a glance, to know the probability, of say, 6 sets and 15 flips?

My working formula is $\frac{1}{2^x}*y$

This tells me that for 6 sets of 15 flips, the result is $$0.23... = \frac{1}{2^6}*15$$

I am not entirely sure if thats foolproof. If I were to plug the numbers x=3 and y=20, then I get

$$2.5... = \frac{1}{2^3}*20$$

Which, 250% does not seem like the right answer. So I am sure my formula is missing something. But I don't know what.

Comment: Hint:  easier to work backwards.  What is the probability that none of the index pairs are $HH$?

Comment: Are the coins fair?

Comment: @lulu for 2 sets, and 1 flip, the chances that none of the index pairs are HH is 3/4 right?

Comment: @joriki yes the coins are fair.

Comment: Yes, $\frac 34$ is correct for one pair.

Comment: @lulu so then I would take $2^x$ for x sets. therefore $1-\frac{2^x-1}{2^x}/Y$ would give me my answer? Since getting all heads is $\frac{1}{2^x}$ the opposite is true for everything else. I divide the answer by the amount of flip, Y, and take that difference from 1. Does that seem right?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what you mean.  By "$x$ sets" do you mean you have $x$ indexed collections of trials?  So in the actual post question, $x=2$?  And if I am right about that, are you then looking for single indices that are all $H$?

Comment: @lulu Yes that is all correct. The example given is 2 sets (x), of 5 flips (y). And I am looking for each set/collection to share an index that are all H. I am looking for the probability of any index from 0 to (y-1) to be H in ALL collections.

Comment: Right, so in that case, if you fix an index, the probability that it is not all $H$ is $\frac {2^{x}-1}{2^x}$.

Comment: @lulu I think I see where I went wrong. Instead of dividing by Y, I would take the result and power that to $y$. Giving me $1- (\frac{2^x-1}{2^x})^y$

Comment: If $y$ is the number of tosses, then I agree.

Comment: @lulu Awesome. Thanks for the help, If you'd like to formulate that into an answer I would be happy to give you the green check mark. So that if anyone else stumbles on this they don't have to read through the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To rephrase the question:

You have $x$ random vectors with $y$ coordinates.  Each entry in a given vector is either $H$ or $T$ with equal probability. We imagine that each vector represents the results of $y$ tosses of a fair coin.  We ask for the probability, $p$,  that at least one of the coordinates consists of all $H's$.

It is easier to work backwards.  Letting $q=1-p$, $q$ is the probability that none of the coordinates are all $H's$.  Since the probability one given coordinate is all $H$ is $\frac 1{2^x}$ we see that the probability that one given coordinate is not all $H$ is $1-\frac 1{2^x}$ whence $$q=\left(1-\frac 1{2^x}\right)^y$$\
It follows that $$p=1-q=1-\left(1-\frac 1{2^x}\right)^y$$